# Colon in the Property Placeholder

Tags: java, spring

In our application we have bean configuration in XML file. In XML file I found this line:

```xml
<jee:jndi-lookup id="myVar"
                 jndi-name="java:jboss/application/myVar"
                 default-value="${application.myVar:}"/>
```

Value of `${application.myVar:}` is stored in properties file.

What does colon after `application.myVar` mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all there is nothing about `JSTL`.

The expression `${...}` comes from [`<property-placeholder/>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-context-pphc).

The `colon` means a delimiter between value from property placeholder and the default value.
For example your case:

`application.myVar` the key to resolve value from properties file.

'the empty string after colon' - the default value, if `application.myVar` doesn't exist or is empty.